# How to automate Flutter Integration testing command?

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

I've read and tried integration testing with flutter. I followed this guide here...

https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/testing/integration

Now, to run the integration test I have to type in the following command:

```
flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart
```

My question is, is there a way to automate this inside android studio so I do not have to type in the command manually. I rather just click one button and run the integration test than type the command over and over again.

I'm new in flutter over all so any suggestion will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if you found answer for your question, but I am going to post solution here. Hope it helps.

1. In Android Studio, open the `run/edit configuration dialog` and select `Edit Configurations` as below:

[image]

2. Click on + button and select `Dart Command Line App` configuration.

[image]

3. Give a name for the configuration (ex: integration.dart) and select following:

Dart file: the path of the dart file which has integration test. (ex: app_test.dart)

Working directory:  root path of your project.

Environment variables:  click on folder icon at extreme right in this field and create new environment variable as below:

[image]

Note that, the `http` url will be different in your case. In order to find out that, run the flutter command in terminal and note the `observatory url` displayed in the console. In my case, it was below:

`flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:51150/`

Replace it with yours and click OK.

Once you complete above steps properly and run the `integration.dart` configuration, you should be able to run the command from Android Studio and see the results in IDE.

[image]

Comment: nice one~ Thanks! :D

Comment: I tryied this solution, but I got the follow error: VMServiceFlutterDriver: It is taking an unusually long time to connect to the VM.

Please, Someone can give some tip how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Visual Studio` and I have created a script file `integration_test.sh`.

```
flutter drive \
  --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart \
  --target=integration_test/login_test.dart

flutter drive \
  --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart \
  --target=integration_test/register_test.dart

..
```

To execute the test. I just run `bash scripts/integration_test.sh`

I am also trying to add on `launch.json` with `task.json` still could not figure it out. I will update the answer once everything is working.

Code for `launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter Dev",
            "program": "lib/main_dev.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        },

        ...

        {
            "name": "Flutter Integration Test",
            "preLaunchTask": "IntegrationTest",
        }
    ]
}
```

Code for `task.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "tasks":[
        {
            "taskName": "IntegrationTest",
            "command": "scripts/integration_test.sh",
            "isShellCommand": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a Run Config with for flutter drive using "Dart Command Line App" requires a `VM_SERVICE_URL` Environment. If you'd like to let flutter drive create their own VM instance dynamically, you can configure the `flutter drive` command as an 'External Tool' in Android Studio, and configure created External Tool to run 'Before launch'. Note that the path set on 'Program' points to the Flutter SDK.

[image: flutter drive External Tool config]

You can check this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3450#issuecomment-873065655) for more details.