# Flutter Integration Test run/debug configuration in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-test

I am trying to run/debug some integration tests on a flutter project. my tests are running fine when I run "flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart" on my project.
I am trying to create a Debug configuration in my Android Studio as per following steps in the StackOverflow answer-
[How to automate Flutter Integration testing command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361718/how-to-automate-flutter-integration-testing-command/56286951#56286951)
however, when I try to run the test with this configuration I get the following error

Any pointers about how this can be resolved?

Removing Break points and Flutter clean did not yield any results

```
00:00 +0: Flutter Driver demo (setUpAll)
[info ] FlutterDriver: Connecting to Flutter application at http://127.0.0.1:55319/L_Bm--V4Kjg=/
[trace] FlutterDriver: Isolate found with number: 283666305
[trace] FlutterDriver: Isolate is not paused. Assuming application is ready.
00:00 +0 -1: Flutter Driver demo (setUpAll) [E]
  JSON-RPC error -32601 (method not found): Method not found
  package:json_rpc_2/src/client.dart 110:64          Client.sendRequest
  package:json_rpc_2/src/peer.dart 68:15             Peer.sendRequest
  package:vm_service_client/src/scope.dart 64:23     Scope.sendRequestRaw
```

Run Configuration is as follows[image: This is a AS_Run_config]

Comment: can you share your configuration how have you set it up in AS?

Comment: Just added in the question. I ensure the app is running on 8888 port

Comment: Check out this article which talks about configuration in AS and also read the responses about issues while doing so. Hope it'll help you. https://medium.com/flutter-community/hot-reload-for-flutter-integration-tests-e0478b63bd54

Answer (score 0):

Checking the logs and your setup, the run config is fine and works without issues. The issue here is caused by a "Method not found" error thrown by `json_rpc_2`. Trace where the error is thrown from your test, and see if this could just be an unhandled Exception that causes the issue.

Another workaround here is to set up `flutter drive` as an External Tool, and configure created External Tool to run 'Before launch'. Note that the path set on 'Program' points to the Flutter SDK.

[image: flutter drive External Tool config]

This works well for me, and using this approach, you won't need to set a `VM_SERVICE_URL` Environment for your flutter drive run config.

Comment: Where is the menu above located?

Comment: Run > Edit Configurations

Comment: What do you click after that because I cannot see the `command` option or external tool. I can add a new flutter, dart command line program , flutter test